# Problem with the Return Function in Python in my code

Tags: python, recursion, return

I have been trying to write code for the activity selection problem. I am not using the greedy algorithm method but I just wrote this code on my own. My cod is able to find the max number of activities possible, but in my code, I am having a problem with the input. Here's my code:

```
i = int(input("How many activities are there? Please enter as an integer. "))
list_of_lists = [[[]], [], []]
def check(space):
    x = space.split(" ")
    for b in range(2):
        x[b] = int(x[b])
    if (x[0] >= x[1]):
        space = input("Incorrect start and end times. Please enter a start time which is less than the end time. ")
        check(space)
        return space
    return space
    #ab = space
    #return ab
for a in range(1, i + 1):
    arr = input("Please enter the start time and end time. There should be a space between the two integers. ")
    abc = check(arr)
    print(abc)
    list_of_lists[a].append(list(map(int, abc.split(' '))))
    list_of_lists[0].append(list(map(int, abc.split(' '))))
print(list_of_lists)
count = [0] * i
inn = 0
for ii in range(1, i + 1):
    for jj in range(1, i + 1):
        if (ii != jj):
            if (list_of_lists[ii][0][0] <= list_of_lists[0][jj][0]):
                a = list_of_lists[ii][0][1]
                b = list_of_lists[0][jj][0]
            else:
                a = list_of_lists[0][jj][1]
                b = list_of_lists[ii][0][0]
            if (a <= b):
                count[inn] += 1
        else:
            count[inn] += 1
    inn += 1
count.sort()
print(count[i - 1])
```

So there is a problem with the check function. It is working perfectly when I have the correct type of input. But say, if someone inputs the wrong type of input, then there is a problem. Let me describe with an example.

If I input `2 4` to `arr = ...`, then it is working properly. If I input `6 5` to `arr = ...` and then if I input `2 4` to `space = input(...`, it is working properly. However, if say I input `6 5` to `arr = ...`, then I input `5 4` to `space = input(...`, and then I input `2 4` to `space = input(...`, then it is not working properly. check function is returning `5 4`. I know the problem is with the return but I really do not know how to solve this issue so that it works in the right way.

Comment: You aren't returning the return value of the recursive call to `check`, but you shouldn't be using recursion anyway. Use a `while` loop to repeat code until the proper condition is met.

Comment: Exactly,  In the short term, you can change `check(space)` to `return check(space)`,  but this is a terrible use of recursion.  Just do it with a loop.